# offline cache manifest - one file stuck in old version

Tags: json, html, caching, offline-caching, cache-manifest

I have an issue with offline cache manifests that I don't quite know how to troubleshoot.

1) A .json file which is part of the manifest is stored together with the manifest.

2) I change that file, and verify that it is indeed changed on the server.

3) I re-generate the manifest (it has a timestamp for uniqueness)

4) The chrome://appcache-internals show that the manifest is indeed updated at the expected time

5) The .json file is still in the old verison, ie. different from the version I have on server, even though the manifest itself is verified to have been updated minutes later.

I don't understand while one file of the manifest is still in the old version.

Update:

It seems to primarily be a problem on localhost, on my DEV environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I had two different sites on the same domain serving different cache manifests. They seem to block one another out. By clearing the manifest from site one, site two works like expected and vice versa.

I guess the offline cache specs is only intended for one manifest per domain.